# What is the role of underscore in gjs?

Tags: gnome, gjs

In gjs [docs](https://gjs.guide/guides/gjs/style-guide.html#variable-naming) I found that underscore is used to denote private variables, but what does it do when creating objects with `new` or calling methods? For example in default code that gets generated when creating extension:

```
...
let item = new PopupMenu.PopupMenuItem(_('Show Notification'));
    item.connect('activate', () => {
        Main.notify(_('Whatʼs up, folks?'));
    });
    this.menu.addMenuItem(item);
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see there is the `_()` function, which is a shorthand for [`gettext()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Translation-with-gettext.html). In other words, it marks a string as translatable, and will load the translated string (if available) when it's run by the user.